# GWT JSON based client side (multiple one on top the other) draggable data charts

Tags: json, gwt, charts, client-side

Using GWT on the client side and .NET C# on the server with JSON being the data transport. I would like to send a collection of data points and associated info tip data to the browser/client for multiple data types and I am looking for some client side charting library that would specifically support the following:

1. Draw a line graph for each collection of data points per data type one on top of the other (i.e. one in a row for each data type).
2. Be able to click n drag all the charts (together) just like google maps without seening a break in the line graph as long as there is data on either side of the timeline
3. Be able to manipulate click event on the chart to request further detailed info from the server for the time (to show in a pop up)

I am currently constructing the bitmaps/tiles on the server, store them in a temporary store in memory and then send them to the browser which is I suppose would not be scalable when the number of clients grow and also it is very slow/inefficient.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several client side charting tools with wrappers for GWT.
Here is a list of charts which have gwt wrappers and support line charts:

- [google-chart-tools](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/chart/) ([gwt wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted))
- [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/)
- [Highcharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/) ([gwt wrapper](http://highcharts-gxt.sourceforge.net/wordpress/))

Alternatively you could implement your charts also with a charting framework:

- [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/) ([gwt-wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/choosel/wiki/ProtovisGWT))

Almost all above mentioned charting libraries should support requirement 1 (stacked data) and 3 (interaction) For requirement 2 (drag and drop support) you probably have to do it yourself or extend the charting libraries.